# How to change content in a div jquery/php variables

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php file with variables. In my main file, once I click on the link, I want the text depending on the numbered id.

page.php:

```
include ('variables.php');
<div id="summary"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $title; ?>. 
            <a rel="<?php $nb="1";echo $nb; ?>" id="<?php $id="A";echo $id; ?>" href="#summary">Summary</a></li>    
        <li><?php echo $title; ?>. 
            <a rel="<?php $nb="2";echo $nb; ?>" id="<?php $id="B";echo $id; ?>" href="#summary">Other</a></li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
```

In a separate PHP file (variables.php):

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$completeUrl = $url . $page_title;

if (strpos($url, 'page.php') !== false){
    if ($id="A") {
    $page_title = "page.php";
    $nb = "1";
    $title= "My first title";
    $content = "<h4>My first subtitle</h4><p style='line-height:normal;'>My first content...</p>";
    }

    elseif ($id="B") {
    $page_title = "page.php";
    $nb = "2";
    $title= "My second title";
    $content = "<h4>My second subtitle</h4><p style='line-height:normal;'>My second content...</p>";
    }
    ...
    else {$content = "other content";}
}
```

I miss the jquery function that could do the job.
I've tried something like this :

```
function getContent(id)
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'variables.php',
    data: $content, 
    success: function(data) {
        $('#summary').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

with `<a onclick="getContent('B')...`

I have an error on Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The console should tell you the file and line number where the error was encountered, that would be useful to share - although, I immediately see that you are using a php variable in your javascript (data: $content). edit #2, I think you mean to use the parameter 'id' instead of $content in your javascript function

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX should look something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'getPageContent.php', // This should be a dedicated AJAX php script
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" } // This is JSON
    success: function(data) {
        $('#abstracts').html(data.variable); // Access variables in your returned JSON object
        }
    });
```

I would suggest making something much simpler to develop your skills and understanding of AJAX first, then approach something more complicated like this once you are confident in the flow of information.

Here's a mission for you:

- Create `ajax.php`

  - to randomly post back either: `{success: 'true'}` or `{success: 'false'}`
- Create `script.js`

  - Call ajax.php via the AJAX command
  - Do something depending on what is returned, i.e.
  - - `alert('win!')` for success: true and
  - - `alert('lose!')` for success: false.

Once you have done that, extend the exercise by passing ajax.php a random number between 1 and 100 and modify ajax.php to send true if $_GET['random'] <= 50 and false if > 50. You'll then be sending information, doing something with it, returning a result, and doing something with it.